# Probabilities of Clasiffication in Machine Learning

Tags: python, classification, probability

I'm currently learning Classification in python (Machine Learning). I've practiced some classification methods that I found very interesting (Ej: DecisionTrees, SVM, etc.). As you may now, this methods predict the classes of different cases to come, however, I was wondering if there was a way or method that, instead of predicting classes or labels to differenet subjects, return the probabilities of the subject being x class.
Example:
I have a number of patients who are consuming different types of drugs. For now, i've only split the data into test/train sections

```
df = pd.read_csv("DataSets/drug200.csv")
print(df)

#define x
x = df[["Age", "Sex", "BP", "Cholesterol", "Na_to_K"]].to_numpy()
print(str(x) + "\n")

#Convert bp, sex & cholesterol to numeric values
sex = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
sex.fit(['F','M'])  
x[:,1] = sex.transform(x[:,1])  

bp = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
bp.fit([ 'LOW', 'NORMAL', 'HIGH'])  
x[:,2] = bp.transform(x[:,2])

chl = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
chl.fit([ 'NORMAL', 'HIGH'])  
x[:,3] = chl.transform(x[:,3]) 

y = df["Drug"]

#split data into train/test sets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 3)
```

Now, instead of using a Classification method like for example DecisionTree, is there a way to get the probability of x patient consuming n drug?

Comment: You can use predict_probab instead of predict function on your desired classifier

Comment: Exactly how do i do that? do i have to specify a classification method and then use the predict_probab function?

Comment: yeah, you will have to use a classification method from the library and use predict_probab on it